# Send Push Notification with Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a push notification through a programm to my app/device.

I tried the offical firebase way but it did not work.
There is no error, it just doesnt send it to my device.
I can send it through the firebase online portal to this topic.

```
        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("odysys-d3-statistik-app-firebase-adminsdk-dmiyf-0292d81b4c.json"),
        });



        var topic = "all";




        var message = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message()
        {
            Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "score", "850" },
                { "time", "2:45" },
            },
            Topic = topic,
        };

        string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```

What is wrong with this code? thanks in advance

Comment: What platform are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm trying this on Xamarin and from my external programm with c#

Comment: maybe i wasn't specific enough, are you trying this in iOS/Android? because you need extra configuration in/code in those projects aswell, if you tell me that they are done, one thing that comes to my mind is: In the firebase console, when creating a project, in the platforform configuration (Android/iOS), in the Project Name field, did you use the actual project name of your app? other thing is: the google-services.json file should be set has "GoogleServicesJson" in the BuildAction on Android and GoogleServices-Info.plist as BundleResource on iOS

Comment: your question lacks information, if you could show us how you are receiving the notification in your app maybe we can find the problem

Comment: in my xamarin android project I'm using AppCenter to recieve the notifications. When I try to send a notification through the firebase console everything works fine. Yes I used my actual project name and the json file is correct.

Comment: ok, got it more specifc now, if your response comes sucessful, maybe has something to do with the FCM message, but it seems correct, the event on the app still catches the notification and doesn't show it? or it doesnt even receive it?

Comment: also, have you tried to send it without the topic param?

Comment: The event is not triggering. I can not send the message without a topic